# Javascript - animate tube or wire to write text

Tags: javascript, drawing

Is it possible to animate a vector line with some effects to write text/draw images?

Here's an example of what I'm looking for;

[image]

How would I

1. transition from a straight line to that?
2. Transition from one shape to another?
3. Have it come in from the side and trace the image (like the video games "snake" or "tron cycles")?

In pure programming terms, I assume this would mean moving a point around and leaving a trail.

Preferably this would be vector and not canvas.

Answer (score 2):

The best JS library for vector grapics (IMO) is http://raphaeljs.com/

The following example shows you how to animate shapes
http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html

Something like the following would animate from a square to a triangle

```
var path1 = "M170,220l40,0 0,40 -40,0z",
    path2 = "M290,220l20,40 -40,0z";
r.path("M170.5,220.5l40,0 0,40 -40,0z").attr(dashed);
r.path(path2).attr(dashed);
var el = r.path(path1).attr({fill: "none", stroke: "#fff", "stroke-width": 2}),
    elattrs = [{path: path2}, {path: path1}],
    now = 1;
r.arrow(240, 240).node.onclick = function () {
    el.stop().animate(elattrs[+(now = !now)], 1000);
};
```

Comment: cool, thx. Will visit irc to see if they have suggestions for (3)

Comment: That more than just text thing is made of awesome